# Unity freeze randomly

Tags: freeze, touchpad, unity

My UI hangs and nothing works anymore (mouse not moving, image freezes). I have to switch to TTY and go back to UI to make it unfreeze.

I have the following error in DMESG:

http://pastebin.com/G9pZHBuC

It seems to occur when I'm using the touchpad.

Comment: Can you try to add to `/boot/grub/menu.lst` to the end of the kernel entry which you boot the following: `i8042.reset i8042.nomux=1 psmouse.proto=imps`

Comment: @kirill-a Are you sure this is not a CPU cooling problem?

Comment: It has something to do with the nvidia drivers. When I switch to the intel graphic card the problem doesn't occur anymore.